# React.js and Mobx. 'TypeError: cyclic object value' if i try to find item in the mobx collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-lite

My `mobx` class:

```
class ProductItems {
  products = [
    { id: 1, image: window.location.origin + '/images/tmp/01.png', price: '₴184.21' },
    { id: 2, image: '/images/tmp/02.png', price: '₴311.21' },
    { id: 3, image: '/images/tmp/03.png', price: '₴221.21' },
    { id: 4, image: '/images/tmp/04.png', price: '₴91.21' },
    { id: 5, image: '/images/tmp/05.png', price: '₴221.21' },
    { id: 6, image: '/images/tmp/06.png', price: '₴131.21' },
    { id: 7, image: '/images/tmp/07.png', price: '₴161.21' },
    { id: 8, image: '/images/tmp/08.png', price: '₴101.21' },
    { id: 9, image: '/images/tmp/09.png', price: '₴109.21' },
  ]

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  findById(id) {
    return this.products.find(product => product.id === id)
  }
}

export default new ProductItems()
```

I try access to filtered product:

```
import './ProductDetail.css'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import store from '../../store/products-store'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const ProductDetail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams()
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({})
  useEffect(() => {
    setProduct(store.findById(+id))
    // setProduct(store.products.find(product => product.id == id))
  }, [id])
  const { price, image } = product
  return (
    <section className="product-detail">
      <div>
        Product Page: {id}
      </div>
      <div>Price: {price}</div>
      <div>Image: {image}</div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default observer(ProductDetail)
```

It works correctly and result expectable, but in the console i'm having error messages all the time:

```
TypeError: cyclic object value    react_devtools_backend.js:4026:25
    parseData _product.css:8
    i _product.css:10
    i _product.css:10
    _ _product.css:10
    _ _product.css:10
    l _product.css:10
    emit 1:334
    emit 1:334
    attachRenderer react_devtools_backend.js:16201
    initBackend react_devtools_backend.js:16213
    initBackend react_devtools_backend.js:16212
    setup react_devtools_backend.js:13122
    welcome react_devtools_backend.js:13068
    EventListener.handleEvent* react_devtools_backend.js:13071
    __webpack_require__ react_devtools_backend.js:20
    <anonymous> react_devtools_backend.js:84
    <anonymous> react_devtools_backend.js:87
```

I have no idea why it happens so i can't ignore this error until reason realized.
I hope that someone came across something similar and could share explanations.
Thanks.

### P.S.

more details

```
sergii:~$ node -v
v16.5.0
sergii:~$ npm -v
7.19.1
```

`package.json`

```
        "mobx": "^6.6.1",
        "mobx-react-lite": "^3.4.0",
        "react": "^18.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
```

### P.S.2.

`_product.css` (mention 8 and 10 rows)

```
.product-list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product-list__item {
    background-color: #f7f8f9;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

...
```

### P.S.3

[Git project link](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/reactjs-store-workshop)

Comment: React Devtools bug probably?

Comment: @Danila I tried this before publishing question. I removed the React Devtools no issues then. I reinstalled Mozilla React Devtools latest version plugin and issue backs. On one hand i have no error log if Devtools is absent, on other hand React Devtools might be an indicator which helps to detect the problem and reason of the problem could be different, i'm not sure.

Comment: It also says something about `product.css` what if you remove this file? Also, you would better post in on the Devtool Github, since it's clearly related to it

Comment: @Danila, i've pushed my changes to the [git](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/reactjs-store-workshop).